# Rebus #22 needs decoding

Tags: rebus

This is a double puzzle: first, you've got to figure out the kenning (2 words); then you've got to interpret what the kenning means (1 word noun).  An example of a kenning is ***bookworm*** for voracious reader or ***rug rat*** for infant who can't walk yet.  For more info, look at [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/457544/what-kind-of-name-is-underground-railroad/457557#457557) of mine.  Clue:  the final answer is a beach/sea creature.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is it

> clam/shell cracker -> otter? I think otters are known for cracking shellfish open?

Comment: Ohhh, you're right:  I've watched them do it many times.  I forgot.  My bad. I was thinking of a different animal, but your answer is a tie.

Comment: @Wordster what were you thinking of? A marine bird?

Comment: Yup!  See below.

Answer (score 1):

The answer I was thinking of is

> seagull